# SpringBoot CRUD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

I stuck with my Springboot Crud project and i need your helps.Problem is i want to use GET with my `barcode` string variable , and to DELETE and PUT using my `id` int variable but somehow i could not managed to DELETE and PUT with `id` variable and i stuck with this all the day. i will post my code and i will apriciate every help

> Application.java

```
package com.javahelps.restservice;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.javahelps.restservice.entity.User;

import com.javahelps.restservice.repository.UserRepository;

import com.javahelps.restservice.repository.UserRepository2;

import com.javahelps.restservice.repository.UserRepository3;



@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    protected CommandLineRunner init(final UserRepository userRepository , UserRepository2 userRepository2,UserRepository3 userRepository3) {
        return null;



        };
    }
```

> UserController.java

```
package com.javahelps.restservice.controller;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.Session;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    import com.javahelps.restservice.entity.User;

    import com.javahelps.restservice.repository.UserRepository;
    import com.javahelps.restservice.repository.UserRepository3;

    import javassist.tools.web.BadHttpRequest;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/productnames")
    public class UserController {



        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repository;
        private UserRepository3 repository3;

        @GetMapping
        public Iterable<User> findAll() {
            return repository.findAll();
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/{barcode}")
        public User find(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode) {
            return repository.findOne(barcode);
        }

        @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
        public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
            return repository.save(user);
        }



        @DeleteMapping(path = "/{barcode}")
        public void delete(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode) {
            repository.delete(barcode);
        }
        @DeleteMapping(path = "1/{id}")
        public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
            repository.delete(id);
        }
        @PutMapping(path = "/{barcode}")
        public User update(@PathVariable("barcode") String barcode, @RequestBody User user) throws BadHttpRequest {
            if (repository.exists(barcode)) {
                user.setBarcode(barcode);
                return repository.save(user);
            } else {
                throw new BadHttpRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

> UserRepository.java

```
package com.javahelps.restservice.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.javahelps.restservice.entity.User;
@RestResource(exported = false)
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {

}
```

> User.java

```
package com.javahelps.restservice.entity;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity

@Table(name="ProductNames")
public class User {





    private int id;

    @Id
    private String barcode;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private int qty;
    private Date dater;
    private Date datel;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public Date getDater() {
        return dater;
    }

    public void setDater(Date dater) {
        this.dater = dater;

    }

    public Date getDatel() {
        return datel;
    }

    public void setDatel(Date datel) {
        this.datel = datel;

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "='" +", id='"+ id + '\'' +", name='"+ barcode + '\'' + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", category='" + category + '\''
                + ", qty='" + qty + '\'' + ", dater='" + dater + '\''+", datel='" + datel + '\''    +'}';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem....

Comment: @RobOhRob
i want to use GET with 'barcode' variable , DELETE  and PUT with 'id' varaible but i did not mange how. i manage to do these only with barcode variable but i need to DELETE and PUT with 'id' variable

Comment: Still having issues figuring out where you are stuck.... you aren't able to extract the path variables?

Comment: @RobOhRob

In UserController there are some mappings. DeleteMapping with 'id' variable wont but with 'barcode' variable works well. i need to delete only using 'id'variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For delete based on id, since your primary key is not int id you have to write the below custom code in your interface extending JpaRepository.

And in your rest controller you have to invoke it like `repository.deleteById(id);`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="delete from User u where u.id= ?1")
    void deleteById(int id);
}
```

Similarly you may have to write code for your update statement as well (for PUT case).
Hope this helps.